# How to find a string in DataGridView from TextBox?

Tags: c#, string, linq, datagridview

hi i am new to Linq Queries, And this code is copied from internet

```
     object cells = from r in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()where !r.IsNewRowArray.ConvertAll<DataGridViewCell, string>(r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().ToArray, dgvc => dgvc.Value.ToString)where c.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                             select new  cell {
                            rowIndex = r.Index, 
                           columnIndex = Array.IndexOf(c, _textBox1.Text)};
```

and by using the following code i am fiding the string in a datagridview cell.

```
 object cells = from r in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()where !r.IsNewRowArray.ConvertAll<DataGridViewCell, string>(r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().ToArray, dgvc => dgvc.Value.ToString)where c.Contains(_txt)
                             select new  cell {
                            rowIndex = r.Index, 
                           columnIndex = Array.IndexOf(c, _txt) 
 };

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()) {
        if (!r.IsNewRow) {
            c.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}

foreach (object c_loopVariable in cells) {
    c = c_loopVariable;
    DataGridView1.Rows(c.rowIndex).Cells(c.columnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

and changing the color of that cell.

And i want to find the first empty cell in datagridview i have (12 columns and 8 rows) my datagridview is filled by column wise. when it entering to the 8th row it is automatically goes to next column, Code is written below.Where _col and _row is declared globally

```
        dataGridView1[_col, _row].Value = lvI.Text;
                _row = _row + 1;
                if (_row == 8)
                {
                    _row = 0;
                    _col = _col + 1;
                }
```

actually i am filling datagridview from listview. when i check the listview item the datagridview is filled based on column wise. when i uncheck it clears the datagridview cell which contains that text.

i can show the picture of my datagridview for better understanding

[image]

after uncheck it will be like this

[image]

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'IsNewRowArray' and no extension method 'IsNewRowArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Anjali use `IsNewRow` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the cells containing some text, try this code, your old query has some **dependency** and you missed that part.

```
var cells = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
             .SelectMany(row=>dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                              .Select(col=>row.Cells[col.Name]))
             .Where(cell=>Convert.ToString(cell.Value).Contains(textBox1.Text));
```

The `cells` is an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewCell>`

Then the code to change the `BackColor` can be like this:

```
foreach (var cell in cells) {
   cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Note that all the code you copied is useless.

To get the first empty cells, you do the same but with a different condition like this:

```
var firstEmptyCell = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .SelectMany(row=>dataGridView1.Columns
                                    .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                    .Select(col=>row.Cells[col.Name]))
                    .OrderBy(cell=>cell.ColumnIndex)
                    .ThenBy(cell=>cell.RowIndex)
                    .FirstOrDefault(cell=>Convert.ToString(cell.Value) == "");
//The value of firstEmptyCell may be null if there is not any empty cell
```

Comment: I want that cell number

Comment: @Anjali each `DataGridViewCell` has a property called `RowIndex`. As I said the `cells` is an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewCell>`, so you have full access to the information of each cell.

Comment: can you tell me how to find the first empty cell in datagridview

Comment: @Anjali what do you mean by the first? scan the cells through the columns and go to next row or scan the cells through the rows (in same column) and go to next column?

Comment: Can you invite me for chat

Comment: @Anjali no need to chat, it's very simple. I'll update the code right after you answer the question I asked above, you can also update your question (click on `edit`), show some sample of grid data with 4 cells (2 columns, 2 rows) or more...

Comment: it is checking based on column wise i want row wise

Comment: @Anjali what do you mean by `based on column`?

Comment: it is checking Horizontally not Vertically. i want vertically

Comment: Thanks it is working. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: By using Linq how can you sort the datagridview

Comment: @Anjali it's a big problem, please try asking it in another question.

Comment: i ask a question check that one How to sort datagridview?